# fast way to run openvpn client with any conf under windows

Tags: windows, vpn, openvpn

It was  so silly for me under Windows to to "run openvpngui --> go to tray --> right click --> foo --> connect" inorder to connect to a server. 
So hier is the way i got it faster

if anybody has a better way please post it.

update: i am not able to figure out how can i minimize the openvpn session window into the system tray. I tryed RBtray but it didn't work within this window.

Comment: down voted! Seriously! Comment  at least the reason.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin → openvpn.exe properties → compability → run prog as admin
- Go to C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config → *foo*.ovpn properties → open with openvpn.exe
- open *foo*.ovpn with a text editor and add or change the line 'auth-user-pass' to 'auth-user-pass *login*.conf' or to 'auth-user-pass X:\\path\\to\\*login*.conf' if the *file* located in another directory.
  (For security reasons i prefer to locate the *login.cong* file in a truecrypt container)
- add  the username and password to *login*.conf (under each other)
- add shortcut of *foo*.ovpn to desktop and double click it when needed